# React Navigation Drawer OnPress Not Firing Correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation, onpress

I am using react native and react navigation.  I am creating a react navigation drawer and then inside of the drawer using my own format.  I am struggling to get my logout button to work correctly.

This works fine:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.logoutUser()}>
     <Text style={{margin: 16,fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Logout</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

But I want to include an alert and make sure the user wants to sign out.  This doesn't work. It signs out the user/ next time I log into the app I can see that they are logged out, but it doesn't trigger a refresh for my app until I manually refresh it.

```
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>
          Alert.alert(
            'Log out',
            'Do you want to logout?',
            [
              {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {return null}},
              {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => {
                this.props.logoutUser
              }},
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          )  
        }>
        <Text style={{margin: 16,fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Logout</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

For reference, here is how I am rendering login screen vs main page (props.restoring) changes based on if the user is logged in or not.  For some reason it only updates with the top call, I am wondering if the drawer or alert affect how I call the function:

```
const ChatAppComponent = props => {
  if (props.restoring) {
    return <ActivityIndicator style={styles.activityIndicator} />
  } else {
    if (props.logged) {
      return <DashboardNavigator />
    } else {
      return <AuthScreen />
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:  Adding in the logout function

```
export const logoutUser = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sessionLoading());

    LoginManager.logOut();
    firebaseService
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(async () => {
        await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
        await GoogleSignin.signOut();
        dispatch(sessionLogout());
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(sessionError(error.message));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: What are you doing in `logoutUser` props?

Comment: I added in the logout function above since it's easier to read.  The sessionLogout returns the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has to do with async await.  Not sure why it doesn't work with async await before, but I had to move the dispatch action above the Google methods.

```
firebaseService
          .auth()
          .signOut()
          .then(async () => {
            dispatch(sessionLogout());
            await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
            await GoogleSignin.signOut();
          })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this function using redux.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>
   Alert.alert(
        'Log out',
        'Do you want to logout?',
        [
          {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {return null}},
          {text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => {
            this.props.dispatch(this.props.logoutUser()); //here
          }},
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      )  
    }>
    <Text style={{margin: 16,fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Logout</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

As the logout function is a redux action.

Comment: Dispatching should take place in the action creator.  I did move the alert to redux and now it is working, but I have to go through the alert twice/ click logout twice.